# Variational formulation of a pde

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, elliptic-equations

Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $a\in(-1,1)$, and:
$$ X_f=\{V\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty))\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)): E_a(V)<\infty, V(x,0)=f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}, $$
where:
$$ E_a(V):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty)}y^a|\nabla_{x,y}V(x,y)|^2\,dx\,dy. $$
I want to prove that if $U\in X_f$ is a classical solution of:
$$ \text{div}(y^a\nabla_{x,y}V)=0,\quad\text{on }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty),$$
$$ V(x,0)=f(x),\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
then we have that:
$$ E_a(U)=\min_{V\in X_f}E_a(V).$$
How i can prove this fact? I have no idea, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please fix missing parentheses in the definition of $X_f$.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: It might help if you go the other way first. Show that a solution of your minimization problem solves your pde. If your pde has a unique solution they should then be the same.

Comment: Much better.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ruy can you give any hints please?